# Fresnel half-period zone

Tags: diffraction

I am following this set of lecture notes (see below). I understand  that the idea is to evaluate the Fresnel integral for the circular aperture using the graphic method. However I don't understand at all what the lecture notes are tying to tell me. Could someone please either point me to a good explanation of the phenomena or preferably paraphrase the content of those slides?

Thank you

[image]
[image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I recall that I understood this fairly easily using the [Cornu spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply:

When you want to determine the final intensity of a diffraction pattern at a particular point P, you need to sum the contributions of light from every possible point Q in the aperture at that point. This means that for each little bit of the aperture you need to compute the distance PQ, and in particular the phase shift (given by $2\pi$ times distance divided by wavelength).

Now adding all those infinitesimal contributions takes a complicated integral. Luckily, for circularly symmetrical apertures where P is on the axis of symmetry, you can take the integral one annulus at a time (all points at the same distance off axis are the same distance from P). Each of these annuli adds an intensity contribution with increasing phase shift - so adding them all together leads to the spiral.

Now if you only allow light through those areas of the circular aperture which contribute to the part of the spiral that goes up (positive Y), then you can increase the intensity at the spot by a lot - this is the concept behind the Fresnel half-zone plate. This is illustrated in the following diagram (adapted from figure 136 in your presentation):

[image]

As an interesting side note, if you could somehow change the phase for each annulus so all components end up with the same phase, then you would stretch out the spiral into a straight line which would be even more efficient. And this is exactly what a conventional convex lens does... I hope that additional insight helps, rather than confuses!

**ADDENDUM**

You asked explicitly about Poisson's spot. To understand how that works, we look again at the spiral diagram (the sum of all those infinitesimal annuli). If you take the integral all the way to infinity, you end up at the center of the spiral. If you leave out some small part of the integral, say the first couple of rotations, the amount you are left with is the vector from the center of the spiral ("all the aperture") to the point on the outer part of the spiral ("the integral for the first bit") - and because the spiral becomes smaller only slowly, the magnitude of that vector is almost independent of the size of the obstacle (as long as the obstacle is small). This is why a bright spot is visible on axis for a circular obstacle.

There is a fun anecdote associated with this. When Poisson first heard of the theory of light was a wave, he was outraged - he thought it was the stupidest thing he had ever heard. Being a very clever man, he proceeded to "destroy" the arguments of the wave theory people by demonstrating that if this theory were actually true, it would have to result in a bright spot on axis right behind a circular obstacle. Hahahahaha - this was so obviously ridiculous and wrong that the wave theory would be sent back under the stone it came from. And then somebody did the experiment and the spot was there... The funny thing is that it was named for Poisson (who was forever reminded of this "blunder") and not for the person who actually did the experiment - Dominique Arago. See for example [Poisson's spot: the greatest burn in physics](http://io9.com/5707749/poissons-spot--the-greatest-burn-in-physics)

Comment: thank you for that insight, this does clarify the integral part, but I am still a bit bewildered as how this leads to the half period zones (slides 227,228,229)?

Comment: See whether my update (diagram) makes sense.

Comment: Let me try to understand this; when we move around the circle (on the right), then connecting O and any point on a spiral we get the a phasor. This phasor is the result of the interference of light from going from every possible point on the aperture to that point. The real part of the phasor corresponds to the actual magnitude of the light - similarly as when we are dealing with complex exponentials - and the complex component has no physical meaning. But why are the boundaries between zones are so sharp? To illustrate that the intensity sometimes reaches 0?How does this lead to Possion spot?

Comment: It's the magnitude of the phasor, not the real part, that corresponds to the intensity of the light. The series of green semicircles that I drew indicate a significant intensity of light, with a 90° phase shift compared to the phase of the undiffracted light (the phase of the on-axis component). This does not explicitly address Poisson's spot, which is a special case and might deserve its own answer.

Comment: I see so pi/2 phase shift of that light is just something you need to take for granted when dealing with the graphical method i.e. it is not obvious that this happens if you don't evaluate the above integrals properly?

Comment: No - the phase shift is real. The "straight through" light is the first little bit of the spiral, which is horizontal. The other light has to travel a bit further and gives rise to the phase shift.